# Laravel group messages by date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Conversation model with a hasMany('App\Message') relationship. I want to group all messages by the "created_at" property.
So when i do:

```
$conversation = Conversation::first()->with('messages');
```

It should return something like this:

```
{
    "conversation_name": "some conversation",
    "users": [list of users in the conversation],
    "messages": [
         "today": [collection of messages from today],
         "yesterday": [collection of messages from yesterday],
         "some date": [collection of messages from some date].... etc
    ]
}
```

So far, the best i have been able to do is:

```
Message::all()->groupBy(function($query){
    return $query->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
});
```

But then i only get the messages and not the rest of the conversation information.
I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
Conversation::find(12)->with('messages')->groupBy(function($query){
    return $query->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Anyone have a take on this? :)

Comment: This might be bad, but why don't you get all the messages and then group them up / separate them using php?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested, i fixed the problem like this:

```
class Conversation{

     protected $appends = ['messages'];

     public function getMessagesAttribute(){
         return Message::where('conversation_id', $this->id)
             ->get()->groupBy(function($query){
                 return $query->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
             });

     }

}
```